# Mturk Requester and Worker Sandbox

Tags: mechanicalturk

I'd like to create a HIT with MTurk as a Requester and than "test" the same HIT as a worker. 
Is there anyway I can achieve this ?
I know that there is the Requester Sandbox, but after I ran through the Template process, I can not "test publish" it and hence see it as a Worker.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a pretty simple answer.

Log in to the Worker Sandbox [here](https://workersandbox.mturk.com/) with your requester account and search for your requester name. You can then accept and submit HITs as if you were a worker.

Comment: I have a followup question - I published a batch through the sandbox, but it doesn't seem to be published and is not available from the worker sandbox, even of another user. Can you refer me to what to check?

Comment: Create a new question then - comments on SO are not for posting followup questions, they're for adding to the answer. Perhaps also try contacting Amazon, I haven't done any work with mturk in 2 years...